# Issue connecting to SQL Server using DBI:dbConnect in R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

The first method I tried works.  I first defined an ODBC connection `my_connection_name` with `ODBC data source administrator` on my windows.  Then I use the following code:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(),
                      dsn='my_connection_name',
                      UID = "firstname.lastname@company.com",
                      PWD = "mypassword")
```

This works fine!

However, when I tried to define the driver, server and database name  within the `dbConnect` function. It fails!

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(),
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                      Server = 'my_server_name',
                      Database = "my_database_name",
                      UID = "firstname.lastname@company.com",
                      PWD = "mypassword",
                      Trusted_Connection = "yes")
```

I got error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 08S01: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Interestingly, when I remove the `Trusted_Connection = "yes"`.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(),
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                      Server = 'my_server_name',
                      Database = "my_database_name",
                      UID = "firstname.lastname@company.com",
                      PWD = "mypassword")
```

I got error message like this:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "company.com" requested by the login. The login failed.

I used the same driver, server and database name when I defined the ODBC connection previously.

My authentication option is `ActiveDirectoryPassword`.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Hi zesla. I have a similar issue. Did you manage to solve this problem now?

Comment: For anyone finding this, I have discovered that using Driver = "SQL Server", Trusted_Connection = "yes" was ignored. I had to use Driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" for it to connect.

Answer (score 3):

if using Trusted Connection = Yes, you don't need to supply your username and password. your service account will be used to connect to your sql server.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(),
                      Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                      Server = 'my_server_name',
                      Database = "my_database_name",                    
                      Trusted_Connection = "yes")
```

Comment: without the UID and password, same error message.  When I remove the `trusted_connection='yes'`, it gave the second error message as shown in the post. It seems like it assume `company.com` as server name? because it's after `@`? @metal

Comment: it's the 10th time I configure this type of connection, and every time I still have to come here to remember how to do... Thanks Ed !